# How to open a file that contains a single digit in C shell

Tags: file, file-io, csh

I need to open a file using c shell. The file contains a single integer, and I need to put it into a variable, increase it and put back into the file. Meaning, if the file contains the number 5, I need, after the program runs, that the file contains the number 6. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest not using the C-shell for scripting - that's not what it was designed for. If you have it, use bash instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@` command to evaluate it as numeric expression.

```
% echo 100 > test.txt
% set f = `cat test.txt`
% echo $f
100
% @ f = $f + 1
% echo $f
101
% echo $f > test.txt
% cat test.txt
101
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
expr `cat /tmp/X` + 1
```

(those are backquotes).